# Reverse proxy from "directory" to "server not working

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a docker-compose file that creates 3 apache containers, and an NGINX container.  The apache containers are all different applications that will have their own docker containers.

I want to use NGINX to reverse proxy from a directory off the root nginx container URL to the main parent of the 3 apache instances.

In the configuration below location / works. /parts and /wiki do not.

I have confirmed that all 3 apache containers do work by swapping out the proxy_pass on the / location, so I know the issue is with the nginx config.  However I am a newb to nginx, and am not sure how to figure this out.

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

  sendfile on;

  upstream docker-apache-php {
      server ths_apache_php:80;
  }

  upstream docker-apache-php-two {
      server ths_apache_php_two:80;
  }

  upstream docker-apache-php-three {
      server ths_apache_php_three:80;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-apache-php;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /parts {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-apache-php-two;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /wiki {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-apache-php-three;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, apparently the URLs on the proxy_pass needed to end with a /.  This is now working as I need it too.

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

  sendfile on;

  upstream docker-apache-php {
      server ths_apache_php:80;
  }

  upstream docker-apache-php-two {
      server ths_apache_php_two:80;
  }

  upstream docker-apache-php-three {
      server ths_apache_php_three:80;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-apache-php/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /parts {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-apache-php-two/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /wiki {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-apache-php-three/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
  }
}
```